# Gstreamer videorate framerate vs max-rate

Tags: gstreamer, frame-rate

I want to reduce the framerate of a rstp source to 2 frames per second. I am using a Gstreamer pipeline but I don't understand the difference between the property *framerate* of *video/x-raw* and *max-rate* of *videorate* [documentation here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videorate/index.html?gi-language=c)

From the doc, *max-rate* `maximum framerate to pass through`. So what's the difference between using *max-rate* and doing `videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/2 !`? In my test, *max-rate* does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking exactly the same. Apparently max-rate allows you to input NVMM buffers, while rate as caps don't.

But the docs aren't clear.